# Use pandoc template with bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown

To use a pandoc template with a normal Rmd file I add

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: templateName.latex
```

to the yaml header. But I can't figure out how to do it with bookdown. Neither

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    pandoc_args: --template templateName.latex
```

nor

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    template: tenplateName.latex
```

seem to work in either index.Rmd or in _bookdown.yml.

Comment: Not ```.latex```.  A file extention should be ```.tex```

Comment: The file extension shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    pandoc_args: ["--template", "templateName.latex"]
```

or

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    template: templateName.latex
```

should work. For the first case, make sure to use an array in `pandoc_args`. For the second case, you had a typo (the filename should be `templateName` instead of `tenplateName`). If they don't work, please provide a reproducible example.